# Attempts at client side rendering?

Tags: theming, javascript

What attempts are there (successful or otherwise), to move the heavy work in templating to client side javascript?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/552934/what-javascript-templating-engine-do-you-recommend

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question, the only projects that I am aware of are

- [jQuery Mobile](http://drupal.org/project/jquery_mobile) (I am pretty sure this is abandoned)
- [Backbone](http://drupal.org/project/backbone)
- [Node.js](http://drupal.org/project/nodejs)

There is a related discussion in [Using Javascript frameworks like Backbone with Drupal](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/38394/using-javascript-frameworks-like-backbone-with-drupal) and some of the work for [Spark](http://drupal.org/project/spark) could probably count, too.

I don't have direct experience with any of these, but I am in the early process of determining whether Backbone is a good fit for a particular project.